# How does one know when to use ～ふん or ～ぷん when telling time in Japanese?

Tags: readings, counters, suffixes, time, rendaku

I'm wondering if there are any linguistic reasons or rules that can be applied to find out which to use, or do I just need to memorize them individually?

Answer (score 1):

Well, all the Japanese counters have some irregularities. In this case, the standard counter for minutes is ふん, but in some numbers it changes.

> 1: いっぷん 2: にふん 3: さんぷん 4: よんぷん 5: ごふん 6: ろっぷん 7: ななふん 8: はっぷん 9: きゅうふん 10: じゅっぷん

Comment: However, if you're writing you can use kanji, which is much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule when saying 'x past the hour': if x is 10, 20, 30, 40 or 50 you say '**~じゅっぷん**' not '~じゅうふん'.

For example 15:10 is じゅうごじ**じゅっぷん** and 15:20 is じゅうごじ**にじゅっぷん**
whilst 15:15 is じゅうごじ**じゅうごふん**.

Comment: In fact, that's only one of the irregularities in this counter. 10 it's not the only irregular number of minutes.

Comment: This answer only partially addresses the question. Perhaps you'd care to expand?